# Python: Loop through list of lists matching a value and changing it

Tags: python, list, loops

What will be the fastest way to do this? I have a list of lists and I have to loop through it looking for a particular value on each of the sublists. Once the value is found I have to append a value to another separate list and then change the value that I found. I started doing this

```
for x in f
    if 'nan' in x:
        ef.append(1.0)
    else:
        ef.append(0.0)
```

f is the list of lists so I loop through each list x and check if there's a nan value among the elements of the sublist. If there's at least one nan value among the elements of the sublist x I append 1.0 to ef but if there isn't I append 0.0. Now I need to do this but at the same time I have to change all the nan values on each sublist to 1.0. So I want to do something like

```
for x in f:
    if 'nan' in x:
        ef.append(1.0)
        x[position of nans] = 1.0
    else:
        ef.append(0.0)
```

Is there a way to do this within this loop or must I loop again? I'm dealing with very large quantities of data so I wanted to keep it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity for something like this is linear, you couldn't do better, because you need to inspect every element at least once. Assuming you want to append `1` or `0` in `ef` list only once per sublist, something like this will work:

```
f = [[1, 'nan'], [2, 'nan', 'nan']]
ef = []

for x in f:
    found = False
    for pos, e in enumerate(x):
        if e == 'nan':
            x[pos] = 1
            found = True
    ef.append(1 if found else 0)

print f, ef
```

The [live example on ideone here](http://ideone.com/BDMjy8).

Timing on my laptop (includes building the list):

```
$ time python test.py 
numElements = 15000000

real    0m1.908s
user    0m1.879s
sys 0m0.028s
```

Comment: Heya, sorry I changed your example a tiny bit, because in the question, there's just one `1` attached to `ef` for every entry in `f` that contains `'nan'`, not for each `'nan'`: http://ideone.com/Z4ee3h

Comment: Thx, yeah fair enough, I wasn't clear from the question when the 1 needs to be attached. I think the OP can figure that out himself though, the question was more about whether there's a faster way to do it? :)

Comment: @paul-g yes, thank you. The above poster is right but your answer helps me indeed. I changed the wording a little to make it clearer.

Comment: @paul-g thanks for showing me ideone btw, that's so useful!!

Comment: @Atirag ok, I updated my answer to append just once per sublist? :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using list.append(), it's faster to initialize once using a list comprehension:

```
ef = [[item if item != 'nan' else 1 for item in list] for list in f]
```

This avoids having to find the end of the list after each insertion, and is way more aesthetic.

Comment: hmmm... but the item is never changed there from nan to 1 right? I need to change the item found on the sublist to 1 each time nan is found and nan can be found on many different items inside each list. ef should contain only one entry per each sublist and not per each nan found